# radio button and the bootstrap modal does not work together

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on it for a long time.
I have 2 radio buttons when any of them is clicked

```
1)it should be checked
2)a modal should appear
```

For the first time it works just fine, but the second time I choose the other button it won't be checked but it is checked logically just not show on the screen!
here is my code

```
<input type="radio"  data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-sm" ng-model="choice.tel" value="1" name="tel" > cell phone <br/>
<input type="radio"  data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-sm" ng-model="choice.tel" value="2" name="tel" > home phone <br/>

<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
         <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="modal-body">
                <label>telephone (comma-separated)</label>
                     <input type="text" name="phone" />
             </div>
             <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" >Save changes</button>
             </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: are you using any of angular bootstrap modules?

Comment: I am using twitter-bootstrap

Comment: if you want to use angularjs with twitter-bootstrap i suggest you to use ui-bootstrap or angular-strap...

Comment: isn't that working like you want ? http://plnkr.co/edit/GTF0do?p=preview

Comment: yes it is exctly what I want how did you done that?

Comment: what changes you made?

Comment: nothing just put your code and add libraries that's all but if you really look to work with angularjs you should use ui-angular or angular-strap...